# how to handle cache in express with redis as middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I have a question. 
I am using express 4 and to host my services and my client (angular pages).
I want to add Redis middleware in order to cache response of requests.
I know there are modules which cache request according to user session 
but my situation is a bit different.
Because I want to cache result of all the requests from specific tenant.
one tenant can have multiple users,
In my authentication process I can find out if the specific request belong to the same tenant or not.
As already figured out I have multi-tenant application
Any suggestions how to approach this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit tardy, but you can check module `express-redis-cache` (disclosure, I am the author). It should allow you enough flexibility.